# DBDataReader, rename value

Tags: c#

```
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr["date_payment"].ToString() == "01.01.0001 0:00:00")
            {
                dr["date_payment"] = dr["date_payment"].ToString().Replace("01.01.0001 0:00:00", "Не оплачено");
            }
        }
```

please help, how i can rename this? `date_payment` have DateTime type

Comment: You cannot "rename" a DataColumn which DataType is DateTime. But you don't need to change the value in the field at all. What you want to do is called _formatting_
. Do that where you display the value.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to *format* DataBase value, you need to format the *visualization* of that value.

If, by the way, there is a need to change the date-time format in DataBase, write some *single-run* script (stored procedure, C# server-side code, whetever..)

Hope this helps.